# How to apply indexing to paired rows

Tags: r

I have a following data frame representing paired observations made for each ID:

```
      structure(list(ID = c(9000099, 9000099, 9000296, 9000296, 9000622, 
      9000622), variable = c(2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1), SIDE = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 
      1, 2)), .Names = c("ID", "variable", "SIDE"), row.names = c(NA, 
      6L), class = "data.frame")

          ID variable SIDE
    1 9000099        2    1
    2 9000099        0    2
    3 9000296        0    1
    4 9000296        4    2
    5 9000622        0    1
    6 9000622        1    2
```

I would like to index my dataframe so if variable meets my indexing criteria anywhere, both rows corresponding to this ID will be removed.
For example, if I index data frame by variable = 4, my df will look like:

```
            ID variable SIDE
    1 9000099        2    1
    2 9000099        0    2
    5 9000622        0    1
    6 9000622        1    2
```

if I index by variable = 1, the data frame will be as follows:

```
          ID variable SIDE
    1 9000099        2    1
    2 9000099        0    2
    3 9000296        0    1
    4 9000296        4    2
```

Is there any way to do it without transforming my data frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a small function like this:

```
Indexer <- function(value) {
  dropme <- unique(df[df$variable %in% value, "ID"])
  df[!df$ID %in% dropme, ]
}
```

To apply it, just do:

```
Indexer(4)
#        ID variable SIDE
# 1 9000099        2    1
# 2 9000099        0    2
# 5 9000622        0    1
# 6 9000622        1    2
Indexer(1)
#        ID variable SIDE
# 1 9000099        2    1
# 2 9000099        0    2
# 3 9000296        0    1
# 4 9000296        4    2
Indexer(c(2, 4))
#        ID variable SIDE
# 5 9000622        0    1
# 6 9000622        1    2
```

Of course, this function is unique to the `data.frame` that you have shared. You should modify it so that you can specify the dataset name, the "variable" column, and the ID column. For example:

```
Subsetter <- function(indf, value, look.in, group) {
  dropme <- unique(indf[df[[look.in]] %in% value, group])
  indf[!indf[[group]] %in% dropme, ]
}
```

Try it out:

```
Subsetter(df, 1, look.in = "variable", group = "ID")
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data.frame is called `df`, you can do :

```
df[df$ID!=(df[df$variable==index,"ID"]),]
```

where `index` is the value of variable you want to exclude.

For example :

```
index<-4
>df[df$ID!=(df[df$variable==index,"ID"]),]
       ID variable SIDE
1 9000099        2    1
2 9000099        0    2
5 9000622        0    1
6 9000622        1    2
```

Comment: Thank you both very much! I am really impressed, you found solutions in a couple of minutes!